# Jackson fails to serialize property

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

In my SpringBoot application, I have defined a Controller in the following way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/book")
@Slf4j
public class BookController {

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createBook(@RequestBody BookCreationPayload payload) {

        log.info(payload.getName());
        log.info(payload.getAuthor());
        log.info(payload.getEBookReference());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Created successfully!");
    }
}
```

The corresponding payload is defined like this:

```
@Data
public class BookCreationPayload {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String eBookReference;
}
```

When I hit the endpoint with the following requestbody, I get null for property `eBookReference`.

```
{
    "name":"Kafka on the Shore",
    "author": "Haruki Murakami",
    "eBookReference": "https://www.pdfdrive.com/kafka-on-the-shore-e191718472.html"
}
```

Now if I change the property name to `electronicBookReference`, it works just fine. I think Jackson fails to serialize it due to some naming convention issue but I don't exactly know what's happening.

This is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sandbox</name>
    <description>sandbox</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Is there any @JsonProperty annotation at field level in your DTO ?

Comment: Not really no. But if I do this  @JsonProperty("eBookReference")
    private String eBookReference, it fixes the problem. The thing is I don't want to use @JsonProperty, I want to know why Jackson isn't serializing the property.

Comment: Please provide more info on SpringBoot & Jackson version you are using, if possible add your pom.xml or build.gradle file in question

Comment: Lombok.Data->[GetterAndSetter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter)>Smallprint: "For generating the method names, the first character of the field, if it is a lowercase character, is title-cased, otherwise, it is left unmodified. Then, get/set/is is prefixed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @xerx593 in comments the problem is regarding naming convention & Getter Setter method generated by Lombok the solution if you don't want to use @JsonProperty @JsonCreator is to create Getter & Setter method manually as below.

```
public String geteBookReference() {
    return eBookReference;
}

public void seteBookReference(String eBookReference) {
    this.eBookReference = eBookReference;
}
```

This works with above mentioned request payload you mentioned bcoz Jackson uses class getters and setters methods for serialization and deserialization. What follows "get", "is" and "set" in those methods will be used as the key for the JSON field.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it does work. But why do I need to rename the Getters and Setters? When you referred to naming convention, what exactly did you mean? This doesn't end here. For example, if you use a `boolean` field in the property, it doesn't serialize the same way as a `Boolean`. I was wondering if you could provide me with a proper documentation about the convention.

Comment: Jackson uses class getters and setters methods for serialization and deserialization. What follows "get", "is" and "set" in those methods will be used as the key for the JSON field & not field name.

Comment: I have edited the answer hope this answer your question, as far as Boolean & boolean is concerned, primitive data types cannot be initialized to null values so the weird behaviour is justified !!

Comment: "What follows "get", "is" and "set" in those methods will be used as the key for the JSON field & not field name". I am sorry but this statement doesn't seem to be completely accurate. If I create a getter called `getDummy()` and return `eBookReference` and pass `dummy` as a key, it doesn't serialize the value.

Comment: If you modify getter modify setter as well, getter will be used while serialization, setter during deserialization