# Spring Boot having empty constructor prevents reading body in Postman POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am following a spring-boot tutorial, and I, trying to create a method to add new user to a user list (for now), I noticed that having an empty constructor in the "User" class prevents spring-boot from taking the values from the body of the request,

I do a postman requset to http://localhost:8080/users
with a raw json body

deleting the line with the empty constructor seem to solve this problem. I don't understand why..

why deleting the empty constructor solves the issue? what am I missing?

I am kinda new to spring
any help will be appreciated, thanks!

the User class:

```
public class User {

    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Email;
    private String Password;


    public User() {} //deleting this seems so solve issue

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String password) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
}
```

the UserService Class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {

    List<User> users =new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList(
            new User(1, "ff", "1", "1"),
            new User(2, "qqq", "qq", "qqq")
    ));


    public List<User> GetAllUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public User getUser(int id) {
        return users.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getId() == id)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
    }
}
```

the user conroller class:

```
  @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userService.GetAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping("users/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id){
        return userService.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/users")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userService.addUser(user);
    }
```

}

and the class with the main method:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TodoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post and add a focused question.

Comment: @Turing85  thanks, I edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080983/when-does-jackson-require-no-arg-constructor-for-deserialization) answer your question?

Comment: @Turing85 if it does, then I don't understand how so..

Comment: Short answer: there are no setters. Solution: add setters for all fields of the class User.

Comment: Longer answer: if you provide a no-args you must provide the setters too. But if you provide only an all-args constructor and no no-args constructor then setters are not mandatory.

Comment: thanks @Mar-Z ! adding setters solved the issue, but I'm still a bit confused about the reason to this behavior, could you please elaborate or refer me to an explanation about this subject? (its not a java feature right? its something in spring that I'm missing?)

Comment: It's the Jackson library. Standard for dealing with JSON objects in Spring Boot. It translates JSON objects to Java objects and back. It's called serialization/deserialization. There are 4 different ways it can do it depending on constructors provided in Java object. All four well explained in the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080983/when-does-jackson-require-no-arg-constructor-for-deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex K real reason for this weird behavior is how Jackson uses your getter/setter to serialize the object, its expected member variable to start with lowercase in your case your variables start with uppercase, leading to this weird behavior, if your member variables are not following java convention then it can lead to weird behavior as Jackson expect your variables to follow it

```
public class User {

    private int Id;  // change them to lowercase id
    private String Name;
    private String Email;
    private String Password;

    /*private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;*/
```

Refer this for more info -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75884462/16769477